# in f#, bind to a value from a c# library

Tags: f#, interop

I have a F# DLL and a C# DLL.

The C# library has a namespace `Library` with a class `Toolbox` that contains a member `FUND_BITS` like so:

```
namespace Library {
    public static class Toolbox {
        public static uint FUND_BITS = 0;
    }
}
```

and then in the F# library I have a binding:

```
let bf = Library.Toolbox.FUND_BITS
```

Now, I use `bf` in several functions defined in the library.  When I change the value of `FUND_BITS`, I would expect that all of the F# functions would then use the updated value because I've binded `bf` to refer to `Library.Toolbox.FUND_BITS`, and have not declared it to be a mutable copy or anything.  However, I have found that the functions use a stale value of FUND_BITS rather than the updated value.

Am I misunderstanding how F# creates immutable bindings to values?  If so, I have not been able to find a way to bind in a manner that will update with changes, for instance:

```
let bf = &Library.Toolbox.FUND_BITS
```

Comment: `uint` is a value type; why should it have reference semantics?

Comment: I think you want an alias, something F# does not have.

Comment: @ildjarn I know that I'm probably not understanding the functional programming paradigm completely accurately, but I hoped that in this case since I am binding `bf` to a non-constant value type and I am not specifying any mutable assignment, then the default behavior would be to act as a reference; that if I wanted `bf` to be fixed to some value of `FUND_BITS` at a specific point in time that I would need to use some other construct besides a regular `let` statement.

Comment: This is completely unrelated to functional programming, it is semantics built-in to .NET itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, "bind" in this case isn't the same thing as "bind" in the user-interface data binding sense.  The line `let bf = Library.Toolbox.FUND_BITS` is basically a simple assignment statement.  You'll find that type inference shows that the value `bf` is an instance of `uint32`.

If you want to read the value dynamically, you'd need to use a function that reads the value of the static variable each time it is invoked.

```
let bf = (function () -> Library.Toolbox.FUND_BITS)
```

**EDIT** This more concise version is due to [Guvante](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16800/guvante)

```
let bf() = Library.Toobox.FUND_BITS
```

In this case, `bf` will have a type of `unit -> uint32`.

If you want a two-way link between the values, then you could declare a property getter and setter that use the static field as a backing store, but that just scares me.  A better approach would be just to reference the field directly whenever you need to read from it or write to it.

Comment: `let bf() = Library.Toobox.FUND_BITS` is a more compact representation.

Comment: @Guvante thanks very much, I knew there was one but couldn't think of it quickly enough.

Comment: Thank you for this solution.  It is pretty light-weight, though I still wish there was some way to access the current value of `FUND_BITS` without the parentheses of: `( bf() )`.
Can't decide if I'll stick with this function call approach or putting in the term `Library.Toolbox.FUND_BITS` directly at each access.